# Would implementing a CDN involve moving images and changing path names?

Tags: cdn

I'm just learning about CDNs, so please forgive if this is a dumb question.
Would implementing a CDN involve moving images and changing paths?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a CDN (Content Delivery Network) is at it basis nothing more that a set of webservers.

If you want to host files on a CDN you must copy your files to the CDN servers and then use the full CDN address that points to those files on those servers on your own webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CDN on the same server but different URI. For instance, having your page in: www.example.com with cdn: cdn.example.com (with cdn.example.com as a vhost alias) should be faster then getting all data only from www.example.com, i think it's because of the number of http connections related to the address.
Of course it's best if you have it in another server, in this case you have to copy everything.

Comment: This won't be any faster in general case. The only reason why that could be faster is the client deliberately deciding to reduce the load on one host.

Comment: normally browsers have a maximum number o connections per host. if you have 2 hosts surely it will be faster because it uses more connections (because it's divided). Of course, best performance would be from a professional dedicated content delivery network, with load balancing, etc, but it's much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  You can use a service such as [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) which requires only a modification of some of your DNS settings.  In short, the service determines which files being served are static, and caches those in its network, generally reducing overall traffic to your servers.  You also get the benefit of any geographical distribution the service provides that your own hosting service might not.